# After the Crew Dragon's success, does Boeing's Starliner still offer value?

Tags: spacex, crewed-spaceflight, dragon-v2, boeing

Boeing's Starliner is more expensive than Crew Dragon and seems not to offer any significant advantages. Is there still value to NASA or other parties in the future to having a choice between the two?

Comment: I adjusted the wording to avoid close votes for "primarily opinion-based answers". Feel free to edit further.

Comment: "unlike redundancy" https://kscddms.ksc.nasa.gov/Reliability/Documents/Preferred_Practices/3003ksc.pdf

Comment: In addition to @OrganicMarble's "dissimilar redundancy", another advantage of multiple suppliers is that this overcomes the problems associated with a monopoly. Note how Russia charged more and more and more to launch US astronauts to the ISS after the end of the Shuttle program. They could do so in part because the Soyuz was the only game in town. Being the only game in town invites that one game to charge whatever they want and to undergo technical stagnation. It is very much in NASA's interest to have multiple suppliers.

Comment: Can you extrapolate on what value you believe there was in Starliner *before* Crew Dragon's launch and ISS docking? From what I have seen, no one thought that *Starliner* specifically provided any value. Rather the only value was in (potentially) having a second program to get to space from US soil.

Comment: @TylerH there were certainly a couple of things speaking for Starliner specifically: Boeing being long-established and well-connected, capsule launches on a bunch of different rockets including the Atlas which has an excellent safety record, lands on dry ground... I think many would have bet on Boeing as best-positioned to get the first Commercial Crew launch up and maybe even converge on a better price tag than SpaceX.

Comment: It sure offers value to Boeing! :-) (Which is nothing to be sneezed at these days.)

Comment: Crew Dragon's not a complete success until the astronauts are landed safely on it,  IMO.

Comment: The Ford Model T was a success, why did car development not stop right there ?

Comment: Second-sourcing is always a good tactical idea and so's third-sourcing: make companies compete, and keep them hungry. You know, 'competition'. The reason suppliers like Boeing became greedy and lazy is because for decades their friends in Congress approved mergers and consolidations and steered contracts towards the big boys. That and a revolving-door.

Comment: If the Boeing Starliner comes with MCAS, then the answer is NO.  :)

Answer (score 53):

Commercial Crew awarded two providers for [dissimilar redundancy](https://blogs.nasa.gov/commercialcrew/2020/04/).

> This is exactly why NASA decided to select two partners in the commercial crew effort. Having dissimilar redundancy is key in NASA’s approach to maintaining a crew and cargo aboard the space station and to keeping our commitments to international partners. It also allows our private industry partners to focus on crew safety rather than schedule. The safety of our commercial crew team always will remain as our top priority.

This is especially important in case SpaceX's Crew Dragon or Russia's Soyuz have an issue. When Soyuz MS-10 had an [in-flight abort](https://www.nasaspaceflight.com/2018/11/soyuz-ms-10-abort-sensor-failure-booster-separation/), NASA's access to space was put in jeopardy. Fortunately, the issue with Soyuz was quickly rectified before the ISS needed to rotate its crew.

Comment: For the same reasons, Airbus uses 3 primary and 2 secondary flight computers, only one of which is needed for safe operation. The secondary flight computers are made by a different manufacturer with a different hardware platform, different CPU architecture from a different manufacturer, different operating system, different programming language, and different compiler than the others. *Within* each of the five computers, each command is computed twice by two independent channels, again developed in different programming languages by different teams.

Comment: Simlarly, for the same reason, most large airlines fly both Airbus and Boeing airliners. Imagine, if an airline had Boeing B737-MAX as their *only* airplanes.

Comment: @JörgWMittag whoa, that is really interesting.

Comment: Of course, the other way to look at this is that it is a very convenient way for government funding to prop up unviable commercial companies, without the accusation of "socalist economic policies." Arguably, the only reason why GE and P&W have both survived as commercial aircraft engine manufacturers is because of covert subsidy for their military programs where two suppliers are considered better than one. In a truly capitalist world, P&W's civil engine business would have died when the JT-9D stopped being the state of the art..

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag: Even if some airline does fly all Boeing airplanes, or all Airbus, potential passengers can fly the Airbus airline if the Boeings are grounded, or vice versa.

Comment: I did not think I would see an answer that changed my mind, but I did.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Both South West and Ryanair almost made it to that point...  Another few years before the grounding and both airlines would have been destroyed - right now, they both fly legacy 737s alongside their grounded MAX's but a few years from now...

Comment: @alephzero - you can look at it like that, but if there was only a single supplier they could charge as much as they wanted and it could be even more expensive.

Comment: Here two conflicting effects come into play. If you fly a single model fleet, then you have the simplest possible fleet in terms of maintenance, pilot training, etc.; yet you remove all available buffer for unforeseen events. To loosely quote from Perrow's [Normal Accidents](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_Accidents) tighly bound (i.e. little or no redundancy), complex systems are bound to fail catastrophically.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Not sure  agree with the statement "most large airlines fly both Airbus and Boeing airliners". Some large airlines like Easyjet have a 100% Airbus fleet since 2011, Ryanair have a 100% Boeing fleet (if you exclude the Lauda A320s), Southwest 100% Boeing, etc. Not all the same model, but all the same manufacturer. And in companies that have a mix, it is often based on the type of aircraft (single-aisle Airbus vs twin-aisle Boeing for instance).

Answer (score 8):

It seems NASA likes having two different options for flying humans in space. That's probably why they still have flights booked from Roskosmos.

Competition is good.

Boeing can probably still engineer the price down.

Comment: So two *non-Russian* ones, then...

Answer (score 6):

Space-X has a completely radical design and testing philosophy. NASA can't ignore it, because it produces results very quickly and costs much less than the traditional model. However, NASA also cannot fully commit to an untested paradigm. More generally, it's smart to diversify your portfolio if you don't know enough to pick the winners.

There's also a certain political advantage to any inefficiency that the traditional model produces: it means more jobs for more Americans; and if the design process is slower, it means those jobs are more permanent. Allowing tax-payers to invest in the process (by working for Boeing, e.g., or owning a convenience store near a Boeing factory) makes it easier to justify legislators' continued support for NASA's programs.

Answer (score 3):

It would have had been definitely a value to possess some other human rated rocket while Space Shuttle was grounded or later unavailable. This may happen for any rocket.

Comment: isn't that the same answer as [this](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/44635/20636)